# How to Display Brackets Correctly in Code in User Comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, escaping, markdown, redcarpet

When a user posts a comment on my site, I run it through a sanitized markdown formatter on the backend and then display it on the site.

However, this causes the less-than and greater-than signs (`<` and `>`) to come out with their HTML codes (`&lt;` and `&rt;`) inside the user's code examples (which gets marked with `<pre>` and `<code>` tags). The brackets display correctly outside of code, but how do I fix it so they show  up correctly inside code?

In short, I want what now shows up as:

```
 if(a &lt; b)
```

To show up as:

```
if(a < b)
```

This is my code in the helper for marking down the user's comment:

```
def comment_markdown(text)
  renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new()
  markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer)
  safe_text = sanitize text, tags: %w(b i code pre br p)
  markdown.render(safe_text).html_safe
end
```

It's called in the view:

```
 <%= comment_markdown comment.text %>
```

Comment: `comment_markdown` is called from... where? View code?

Answer (score 0):

Rails already HTML-safe's text for display in views; so with your call to `.html_safe` in the `comment_markdown` method, it's getting escaped twice.

Simply remove your call to `.html_safe`:

```
def comment_markdown(text)
  renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new()
  markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer)
  safe_text = sanitize text, tags: %w(b i code pre br p)
  markdown.render(safe_text)
end
```

Comment: `.html_safe` marks the String so it doesn't get escaped. If I remove it I get `<pre><code>3&amp;&lt;4</pre></code>` instead of `3<4`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood its point. How about putting `<%= raw(comment_markdown comment.text) %>`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'll just use Redcarpet's `filter_html: true` option to prevent any security issues from iframes and the like. Then I don't need to sanitize the text, so it doesn't escape text inside pre tags, and it displays normally. I just need to see how to configure it so users can't use distracting things like Headers.